# Implementing CSS variables in HTML page

Tags: html, css, image, variables

I have an HTML file that contains many background images and color mentioned in a external CSS file and it is linked inside header tag of the HTML.

I would like to use CSS Variable to capture the path of the background images and colors and use this in the HTML file.

Is it possible to use the CSS variables without using any Javascript or server side language or plugins. I can use pure CSS and HTML only to achieve this. I have also seen the http://lesscss.org site, but they used some plug-ins and that I can not use.

Is this achievable? If it is, would anyone be able to write some example code?

Comment: There is no such thing as css variables. You can dynamically generate CSS and insert values from the controlling language. but that's not a "css variable".

Comment: You mean http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/06/css-variables-webkit-brings-the-css-jackalope-to-life/ ?

Comment: You're not referring to this are you? The FPWD just appeared this year; there are no known public implementations except some nightly builds of WebKit which haven't even landed in any WebKit browsers yet. http://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables

Comment: What do you mean by "capture the path of the background images and colors"? And what do you plan on doing with the "paths" after capturing them? If you are looking for a similar way to create CSS variables with out using JavaScript you could look into using SASS. You would need to install the Ruby gem on your local machine... I am not sure if this goes against your requirements of no "plugins" or not. Basically SASS just makes writing CSS faster, the finale output is still CSS. It is very similar to LESS, but it uses Ruby instead of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't currently possible in a cross-browser fashion, but the capability [is being specced](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/) and should hopefully be available for widespread use in the coming years :)

### Proposed Syntax

```
:root { 
    var-main-background: #f00;
    var-main-color: #111;
}
h1 { 
    background: $main-background;
    color: $main-color;
}
```

***Note:** This is not currently usable in browsers, so you'll have to resort to using a workaround such as LESS or SASS in the meantime.*

Answer (score 0):

I Think the only way to achieve this is using LESS.

http://lesscss.org/

Answer (score 0):

There are CSS variables in LESS, everyone please take a look at the question before you downvote.

LESS is a javascript file that will substitute these CSS variables for their respective values. There is no way to achieve this with pure HTML and CSS. That's why LESS and other dynamic stylesheet languages were created in the first place.

Comment: "I have also seen the lesscss.org site, but they used some plug-ins and that I can not use." Ostensibly, LESS is out of the question, if not other dynamic stylesheet languages. Question is incredibly unclear regardless - I'm still waiting for OP to reply to my comment.

Comment: @BoltClock, Please read the rest of my answer: "There is no way to achieve this with pure HTML and CSS. That's why LESS and other dynamic stylesheet languages were created in the first place."

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood your statement about downvoting. Are you referring to downvotes on the question or potential downvotes on your answer?

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to downvotes on the question and the subsequent comments like "There is no such thing as css variables" that are getting votes.

Comment: Ah. I think they're referring to pure CSS variables, since preprocessors like LESS compile variables to pure CSS, a language that doesn't contain any sort of var syntax.

Comment: @MattK, uh... [CSS variables *do* exist](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/). They just aren't usable yet ;)

Comment: @bfrohs, uh... therefore they don't exist :P it's a spec and won't be useful to the OP. it takes many years from spec to implementation and then to full browser support.